# Case when with two conditions using and operator in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ID effectivedate enddate
101. 6/1/2023.   6/30/2023
101. 7/1/2023.   7/31/2023
101. 8/1/2023.   8/31/2024
102. 5/1/2023.   5/31/2023
```

```
Case 
    when effectivedate not between to_date(07/01/2023', 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
                               and to_date(07/31/2023', 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
     and effectivedate between to_date(08/01/2023', 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
                           and to_date(08/31/2023', 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
        then 'yes' 
        else 'no'
```

I need to check two conditions:

- `ID-101` shouldn't have effective date from 7/01/2023 and 7/31/2023
- And that id should have effective date from august

When ID has effective date in
July and also in August then print 'no'

When ID has effective date in August not in July then print 'yes'

The case condition I have written didn't work. For 101 expected result is 'No' but I am getting as yes.

Can you please modify the Case statement to?

Comment: Why do you use two conditions when one would be sufficient?

Comment: Why are you expecting to get "No" for ID 101 from the CASE that you have set out here in your question?  Your sample data shows a rows with ID 101 and "effectivedate" value of August 1 2023, which matches your CASE conditions to return "Yes" ....

Comment: When ID has effective date in July and also in August then print 'no'

When ID has effective date in August not in July then print 'yes'

Comment: @Maddy Can't this be simplified to print `yes` if for a given ID no date except for a date in August occurs?

Comment: You should please also show the expected result of your query. Is this what you need? https://dbfiddle.uk/IrZK6dCS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `COUNT` analytic function and conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT id,
       effectivedate,
       CASE
       WHEN COUNT(
              CASE
              WHEN effectivedate >= DATE '2023-08-01' AND effectivedate < DATE '2023-09-01'
              THEN 1
              END
            ) OVER (PARTITION BY id) > 0
       THEN CASE
            WHEN COUNT(
              CASE
              WHEN effectivedate >= DATE '2023-07-01' AND effectivedate < DATE '2023-08-01'
              THEN 1
              END
            ) OVER (PARTITION BY id) = 0
            THEN 'yes'
            ELSE 'no'
            END
       ELSE 'undefined'
       END AS result
FROM   table_name
```

*Note: you do not define what the result should be if there are no values in August.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, effectivedate, enddate) AS
SELECT 101, DATE '2023-06-01', DATE '2023-06-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, DATE '2023-07-01', DATE '2023-07-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, DATE '2023-08-01', DATE '2024-08-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 102, DATE '2023-05-01', DATE '2023-05-31' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | EFFECTIVEDATE | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | no |
| 101 | 2023-07-01 00:00:00 | no |
| 101 | 2023-08-01 00:00:00 | no |
| 102 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | undefined |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7aHoaej8)

Comment: @JonasMetzler I had edited the question before I'd seen your comment. It's been fixed.

Comment: this logic works. But, can you explain in detail what you have written.

Comment: @Maddy You can read the query almost as if it was English: If the `CASE WHEN` the `COUNT` of `effective_date`s in August 2023 for each `id` partition is greater than `0` `THEN` check if the `CASE WHEN` the `COUNT` of `effective_date`s in July 2023 for each `id` partition is zero `THEN` output `'yes'` `ELSE` output `'no'` (and if the August `COUNT` is not greater than zero then output `'undefined'`).

Answer (score 0):

Logic to get your goal is self join the table and compare the date of 2 table and then in select you get the result.

I tried to give answer in **Oracle**, but I worked some years ago, gave minor error (so you need to correct as Oracle prospective)

```
with yourtable AS
(SELECT 101 as ID, '6/1/2023' as effectivedate, '6/30/2023' as enddate
UNION ALL
SELECT 101,'7/1/2023','7/31/2023'
UNION ALL
SELECT 101,'8/1/2023','8/31/2023'
UNION ALL
SELECT 102,'5/1/2023','5/31/2023'
)
SELECT * from yourtable  a
  left join yourtable  b on a.id = b.id 
and b.effectivedate = DATEADD( a.effectivedate,,,-1 ) and b.enddate = DATEADD(a.enddate,,,-1 ) 
  ;
```

Above thing originally implement in Sqlserver and then converted and its work in Sqlserver.

2 Approach I tried, but first is given proper result, second need to correct at your end

```
declare @table1 table (id int, effectivedate date, enddate date)

Insert into @table1 values 
(101,'6/1/2023', '6/30/2023'),
(101,'7/1/2023','7/31/2023'),
(101,'8/1/2023','8/31/2023'),
(102,'5/1/2023','5/31/2023')

-->>first logic in general that you have to add self table join with current month to last month
select 
    Case when b.id is not null then 'Yes' else 'no' end flag, *
from @table1 a 
left join @table1 b on a.id = b.id 
and b.effectivedate = DATEADD(m, -1,  a.effectivedate ) and b.enddate = DATEADD(m, -1,  a.enddate ) 

order by a.id

select distinct
    Case 
        When b.effectivedate = DATEADD(m, -1,  a.effectivedate ) and b.enddate = DATEADD(m, -1,  a.enddate ) 
            then 'yes' 
        Else 'no'
    End
    flag
    , 
    Case 
        When a.effectivedate between cast('08/01/2023' as date) and cast('08/31/2023' as date)
        and b.effectivedate between cast('07/01/2023' as date) and cast('07/31/2023' as date)
            then 'yes' 
        Else 'no'
    End
    flag1
    ,
    a.*--, b.*
from @table1 a 
left join @table1 b on a.id = b.id 
--and b.effectivedate < DATEADD(m, -1,  a.effectivedate ) and b.enddate < DATEADD(m, -1,  a.enddate ) 

order by a.id
```

[image]

Comment: When ID has effective date in 
July and also in August then print 'no'

When ID has effective date in August not in July then print 'yes' I need check these conditions in one case condition.

Comment: This is not valid Oracle syntax. `@` is not valid before table names. `DATEADD` is not an Oracle function and `cast(... as date)`, while valid, may lead to unexpected issues as it is relying on an implicit string-to-date conversion and if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` does not match then you will either get an error or, worse, unexpected results. If you are going to take the time to answer Oracle questions, it would be much better to learn Oracle's syntax.